# Adding many vertex properties with graph-tool in Python

Tags: python, graph-tool

I have several features to add to each vertex in my graph. The way I know of adding vertex properties to a graph is the following:

```py
g = Graph()
g.set_directed(False)

vprop_feature_name = g.new_vertex_property("int")
g.vp.feature_name = vprop_feature_name
```

Then you could associate data to the vertices by

```py
for data in feature:
    v = g.add_vertex()
    g.vp.feature_name[v] = data
```

However, if I had many features, it would be quite laborious to manually code new variables `vprop_feature_name` for each feature. How could I automatically add features without manually creating new variable names?

Answer (score 2):

There is no need to store each property in its own local variable.  Just use the dict-like access for properties to assign each property under its own name.

Here's an example.

```py
import graph_tool.all as gt

# Example graph
g = gt.Graph(directed=False)
g.add_vertex(10)
g.add_edge_list(list(zip(range(0,9), range(1,10))))

# Create some vertex properties
feature_names = ['foo', 'bar', 'baz', 'wonka', 'wookie']
for name in feature_names:
    g.vertex_properties[name] = g.new_vertex_property("int")

# You can use either dict-like access or attribute-like access.
g.vertex_properties['foo'][0] = 123
g.vp.foo[9] = 789

print(g.vp.foo.get_array().tolist())
```

```
[123, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 0, 789]
```